# How to fabricate ASPX POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post

I'm battling with this for days, I have an ASPX page that has a file upload control and an upload button, and no matter what I do, I can't get the page to accept the automated POST request.

The request body is as follows (all newlines CRLF), all UTF8 == ANSII (no spec chars right now)

```
-----------------------------8cdc74445fc88d0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="btnUpload"

Upload
-----------------------------8cdc74445fc88d0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctrFileUpload"; filename="myfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

This is a test!

-----------------------------8cdc74445fc88d0--
```

The form has multiple buttons, so I need to kinda fill the file upload, and press the upload button. But this doesn't seem to work.

The same page works just fine from a web browser, although, in that scenario there is a viewstate garbage as one of the parts. I tried EnableViewState="false", ValidateRequest="false", EnableSessionState="ReadOnly", but the garbage part is still there when I use the browser.

Am I missing something? Tried studying the RFC and everything, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What is the automated post request?

Comment: One that's generated in my application dynamically, not by user interaction in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST request is post request - it is same for browser and other applications. All you need to accomplish post is set http verb (method) when creating request. If you use .net as request generator from your application, this can be done by setting [HttpWebRequest.Method Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx). There're also examples there

Aaaaargh, everything is clear now.
There're no 'events' in http. Asp.net webforms introduced this(and many others) approach to make developing on web easier as i believe for those who had found difficult to program on web because of http statelessness or were bound to windows development. Asp.net webforms make web development much more like windows development. As i mentioned - there're no events in http protocol. So, asp.net uses viewstate garbage and its dopostbackwithoptions function to bind http client side clicks to server side events. That's why your automated post does not work - when that viewstate garbage is missing, webforms engine has no chance to bind to events. You should handle web request otherwise  - without relying on events

Comment: I have the verb, I do receive the request at server end, but the Upload event is never fired, even though I can see that _multipartContentElement has 2 values in it, with file and upload there.

Comment: So that "btnUpload" part is basically for looks? Can you suggest me how to work around this ASPX behavior to do what I need? Do I have to prequery the viewstate in request 1, and just post it back in request 2?

Comment: Closest answer, although ASP.NET always looks for viewstate.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to compare your post with the post that works..

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the viewstate for a form to work, unless there is something in there that is needed. what you do need is to make sure the name of button that is clicked to submit the form is included in your submitted data.

The clicked control is needed so that asp.net can figure out on which control to raise the click event. the viewstate is just a list of key:value pairs for each control that are different to the default values. by comparing these values to the submitted values it can raise onchange events etc.

Comment: I tried with "btnUpload", but it doesn't seem to work, so I'm guessing I'm missing something. Is there an ordering requirement or something?

Comment: Ordering is immaterial. I'd do as @Richard Friend suggests and use Fiddler to try out the request & compare it against a human submission

Comment: I compared the requests multiple times, tried duplicating everything except "__VIEWSTATE" with no go. As soon as I copied "__VIEWSTATE" value from browser request into my generated POST request, function succeeded. And that's pretty bad, because I have no way how to get that viewstate. And funny thing is that it's disabled in the aspx. No idea how to  disable it even more.

Comment: Disabled in the page, the control, or the application? You can decode viewstate. It's a Base64 encoded string with a MAC at the start

Comment: At the page. It still creates a tag though. It seems I need to make an initial request, get viewstate value out of it and then post it back without modification. And the HTML is not even a valid XML, so no XmlDom there.

Answer (score 0):

I also don'T know what an "automated post request" is, but setting

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

on your form tag might help.

Comment: I also have other functionality on the page that doesn't necessarily requires <input type="file" ... to be filled at all. In that case  www-form-urlencoded is just fine I think.

Comment: If you use www-form-urlencoded, then the post body will look like key1=val1&key2=val2. setting it to multipart/form-data will cause it to look like you've shown above. However this is a side issue & asp.net won't really care. it's just parse the request the same either way